# Variant product_id with API Ruby gem

Tags: api, shopify

I'm using the [Shopify_api gem](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api) to grab products and variants for an app. When grabbing a variant, I can't seem to get the product_id, even though the [API Doc](http://api.shopify.com/product_variant.html#show) says it should be available. Anyone know how I can get the product_id from the variant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.shopify.com/api/product_variant does say product_id should be in the response, and if you inspect the actual response it is. The problem is that ActiveResource doesn't seem to save this as a normal attribute, if you look at https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/master/lib/shopify_api/resources/variant.rb, it uses this as a prefix option. The only way I figure out how to do it right now is

variant.prefix_options[:product_id]

This is also reported in ActiveResource here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3917

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I'd love to see a fix from Shopify, but this is good enough to save me an additional API call, so I'll take it.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534912/shopify-api-variant-not-being-returned-with-product-id-attribute/16707494#16707494